# Did anybody expect that Edward VIII would abdicate?

Tags: united-kingdom, royalty

King Edward VIII abdicated in December of 1936, less than a year after he ascended in January, to marry divorcee (and still-married) Wallis Simpson.

But before his ascension (i.e. during the reign of his father King George V), was it widely expected he was going to force a marriage to Simpson? I understand that the abdication was unusual and a surprise, but was it even conceived of, before it came to a head?

From Wikipedia:

> By October, it was rumoured in high society and abroad that Edward intended to marry Simpson as soon as she was free to do so

In other words, when did it become an inevitability?

Comment: I'm of two minds about this one. It seems to be completely answered on the [appropriate WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdication_of_Edward_VIII). However, the answer is scattered across a rather large page, so I could see some value in a distilled answer.

Comment: The section titled "Options Considered" seems to cover most of that (although it doesn't get into how well informed his *brother* was about all this, but that currently isn't in the question either). The fact that a reasonable person can be pointed to the page, and still not quite see how it answers the question, I think reinforces my suspicion that an answer here digesting it might be a good idea.

Comment: One might also ask whether Edward really expected to abdicate, rather than using the threat to try to force Parliment to change the rather stupid rule about who he could marry?  Certainly from today's perspective, it's as hard to understand as e.g. the marital activities of Henry VIII.

Comment: I think no one expected Edward to abdicate before he made his intention clear of marrying Simpson. After he made his intentions clear, he had either the option of abdicating or abandoning the marriage. What George thought is immaterial as George didn't have a horse in that race. Baldwin, Attlee, and Sinclair ran the game (due to their triple refusal to form any government in case of Edward proceeding with the marriage).

Comment: The Wikipedia article reports that *rumors of the marriage* only began circulating as late as October, while Edward VIII ascended in January, so I think the answer is a safe "no." It's rather strained to go from "the king is having an affair with Ms. Simpson" to "the king is going to abdicate in order to marry Ms. Simpson" when she had not yet gotten her second divorce.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- - move everything  - edit the question so it contains everything in the comments, then delete the comments.  People tend not to answer questions where they have to read pages of comments to understand the question.  OP commenting on questions is an anti-pattern that leads to fewer answers, lower quality answers and a higher probability of closure. Your second comment includes additional research - that should absolutely be in the question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Um, ok